# How can I make the queue process messages faster than it receives them

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ for queue processing but the queue is receiving messages faster than it can process. I don't know how to get round this problem. Adding more processors is not possible as the system can't handle the strain

I want the messages to be processed faster than they are received

Comment: where's the slowdown, I'm assuming you have some of your code somewhere doing work, have you tried profiling your project?

Comment: have you read [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/features.html)?

Comment: show some code, also, how long do these processes take? how much processing power do they require? If not a lot, you could look into multiprocessing to use multiple threads and basically have multiple callbacks consuming from the single channel.